# Facebook & Twitter authentication in Parse data browser settings

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, parse-platform

I just discovered the `"Authentication"` tab in my Parse app's settings. actually I'm using `Twitter` and `Facebook` in my app and don't edited here the `Facebook app id, secret key and Twitter consumer keys`. Is it optional? Because my `twitter` and `fb` login/sign up works correctly without them. When do I need to add these data? I'm setting these infos in my `AppDelegate` and `info.plist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use these settings if you want Parse to handle the login for you. If you're using `PFUser` then you would usually take this option and use the Parse supplied login / registration views. You don't need to do it this way though, if you use the social SDKs and handle the user management yourself that's fine and you should have no issues so long as you keep things separate.